# Default template parameter for explicit function specializations

Tags: c++, templates, specialization

I want to have a set of functions that will accept any `uintX_t` variant, without having to copy/paste a lot of code. So far I'm trying to use "tagging" to determine what write function to call. For obvious reasons, `T = unsigned` doesn't work because I might have `uint32_t`, `uint16_t`, etc.

```
struct number_tag {};
struct hexadecimal : number_tag {};
struct number : number_tag {};

template <typename T = unsigned, typename Tag>
void write(T t);
```

Then later in .cpp file:

```
template <>
void write<unsigned, hexadecimal>(unsigned num)
{
}

template <>
void write<unsigned, number>(unsigned num)
{
}
```

And ideally I want to call it like this:

```
write<number>(10);
write("\n");
write<hexadecimal>(0xFF);
```

How do I write this so that I don't have to do `write<unsigned, number>` and create a bunch of specializations for every `uintX_t` variant?

Comment: Note that code like `write<number>(10);` implies `number` is the *first* template argument, which is why both answers have reversed the order of your template parameters.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't partially specialize functions (boo), but you can do it with more useless structs!

```
struct number_tag {};
struct hexadecimal : number_tag {};
struct number : number_tag {};

template <typename Tag, typename T = unsigned>
struct Writer;

template <typename T>
struct Writer<hexadecimal, T>
{
    static void write(T num) {}
};

template <typename T>
struct Writer<number, T>
{
    static void write(T num) {}
};

template <typename Tag, typename T = unsigned>
void write(T t)
{
    Writer<Tag, T>::write(t);
}

int main()
{
    write<number>(10);
    write<hexadecimal>(0xFF);
}
```

Comment: You might want a `typename std::make_unsigned<T>::type` somewhere in the implementation, depending on what you want to do with negative inputs.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use a separate `write` specialization depending on the `tag`, then add overloads (because functions cannot be partially specialized):

```
template <typename T = unsigned>
void write(T t, hexadecimal tag)
{
}

template <typename T = unsigned>
void write(T t, number tag)
{
}

template <typename Tag, typename U = unsigned>
void write(U num)
{
    write<U>(num, Tag{});
}

write<number>(10);

write<hexadecimal>(0xFF);

write<number, std::uint16_t>(0xFF);
```

[**DEMO**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/03035de1fd53911c)

---

If you want to add a constraint to your function so that it accepts only **unsigned** integer types, the below code does a proper verification:

```
template <typename Tag, typename U = unsigned>
auto write(U num) -> typename std::enable_if<std::is_unsigned<U>::value, void>::type
{
    write<U>(num, Tag{});
}

write<number>(10u);

//write<number>(-1); // triggers error
```

[**DEMO 2**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/f981f4575cf2b5aa)

**Note:** your current declaration `template <typename T = unsigned> void write(T t);` *does not force* the type to be `unsigned`, because the type of a parameter is deduced by a compiler based on the type of an actual argument.

---

If you want to force *any type* passed to the `write` function to be `unsigned`, you can use the below code:

```
template <typename Tag, typename U>
void write(U num)
{
    write<typename std::make_unsigned<U>::type>(num, Tag{});
}

write<number>(-1); // gets converted to unsigned type
```

[**DEMO 3**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/586fff7bc9373945)